# iTunes Media Folder Location seems to act oddly

Tags: itunes, windows

I have a separate partition setup for my Media.

If I set it to F:\ the structure for music is:

F:\{Artist}\{Album}...

If I set it to F:\Music the structure for music is:

F:\Music\Music\{Artist}\{Album}

How can I set it up so that the media is stored F:\Music\{Artist}\{Album}?

Answer (score 1):

In iTunes, go to the File menu, then select "Organize Library" and tick the box next to "Reorganize files in the folder 'music'".

Comment: This will work temporarily to accomplish your objectives. However, iTunes on my Mac does a similar thing. It places some of my music in "[location]/iTunes Media" and some of my music in "[location]/iTunes Media/Music". It is highly annoying and AppleCare was unable to resolve it for me. I can organize my library but it will inevitably start separating new imported material out again randomly.